# Ambiguous Tag: "atom"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

**Current status:**

The tag [atom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/atom) in its current form is used for both:

- The [Intel Atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_atom) CPU architecture
- The [Atom standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29) for XML-based web feeds

**Resolution:**

There already is an [intel-atom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/intel-atom) tag. I've retagged all CPU related questions with it now. That still leaves 8 questions with [atom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/atom).

- Let's find a suitable tag alternative for Atom feeds, maybe [atom-feed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/atom-feed) and then get rid of the ambiguous [atom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/atom) tag by batch-retagging them. I'd also create the appropriate tag wikis.
- Is it possible to stop [atom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/atom) from being recreated?

Comment: There are also atomic operiations.

Comment: Any example for a question on atomic operations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merged & created synonym for [atom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/atom) -> [atom-feed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/atom-feed)

Merge Results

```
updating post history, 16 rows affected
updating posts, 13 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 13 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [atom-feed] and [atom] complete!
Tag Synonym atom -> atom-feed was approved!
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sathya. I wrote short excerpts for both wikis.