# kvm tag ambiguity

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The [kvm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kvm) tag is used for both Keyboard-Video-Mouse switch and for Linux Kernel-Virtual-Machine infrastructure.

There are tags [kvm-switch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kvm-switch) and [linux-kvm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux-kvm)

Is it worthwhile changing all 'kvm' tags to one or other of these? There are 109 questions with this tag, maybe 90-95% could be changed to 'kvm-switch'.

- Is it useful to do this?
- Are there tools to help?
- What happens in future when someone creates a 'kvm' tag?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like a good suggestion.

- This will have to be done manually(Ed: if majority of them are questions which belong to a tag, Mods can do a mass rename and handle the minority questions manually)
- we can create a synonym mapping for [kvm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kvm) to any of the above.

---

Now complete.

```
updating post history, 99 rows affected
updating posts, 78 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 67 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [kvm-switch] and [kvm] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
10 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym kvm -> kvm-switch was approved!
```

Comment: Is it obvious to users that selecting `kvm` will map to a different tag? Or will we get `kvm-switch` tagged questions about Linux virtualization?

Comment: @DanielBeck it'll be something like this: http://i.imgur.com/Cdj26.png

Comment: `osx` isn't a synonym. Do synonyms really appear as normal tags when selecting them?

Comment: @DanielBeck the main tag is shown in the popup but with the synonym highlighted http://i.imgur.com/3om1u.png

Comment: It remains to be seen if this works. My guess is, quite a few users won't get it. Otherwise we wouldn't have `mac` tagged software questions, `osx` related questions tagged `mac-os`, or the `mac-os-x` tag.

Comment: @DanielBeck Unfortunately some people don't seem to understand the concepts very well. I'm still waiting for some consensus on this approach, though

Comment: @DanielBeck `mac-os-x` is gone now. Sathya, I personally would split up the tags into two different ones, and *not* introduce synonyms. I'm still not sure if adding synonym in these cases is really the best way (same goes for [this one](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2700/ambiguous-tag-atom/2702#2702), as Atom processors will be more dominant in the future than Atom XML feeds).

Comment: @slhck the synonym was a suggestion for RedGrittyBrick's question as to prevent creation of [tag:kvm] once again after doing the rename

Comment: Yep, I understand. Well, if that's the solution, fine with me!