# kvm tag should be re-synonymized to linux-kvm

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonym-request

Way back in the early days of SU the tag [kvm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kvm) was synonymized to [kvm-switch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kvm-switch) apparently [without a whole lot of discussion](https://meta.superuser.com/q/3498/144961). But this is resulting in a lot of confusion, as most people seem to expect the tag to refer to [linux-kvm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux-kvm).

I just glanced through the tags.

I found that [linux-kvm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux-kvm) has 281 questions and [kvm-switch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kvm-switch) has 260 questions. However, from a quick glance perhaps a quarter of those questions are actually about [linux-kvm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux-kvm) and should be retagged.

I also propose that the tag [kvm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kvm) be made a synonym of [linux-kvm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux-kvm) to direct the majority of people asking about "KVM" to the correct tag.

Comment: When a tag can have two different meanings, it's never a good idea to synonomize it with one of them.  It will create endless cleanup requirements.  It's better to clean up what's there and let the ambiguous tag die.

Comment: I'd be happy with that, but the tag will come back again unless it's blacklisted.

Answer (score 3):

I half suspect that kvm to most people here means kvm switch, rather than linux KVM. The smart money might be to fix that quarter of those questions that're wrong. Knowing our target audience - it makes a little more sense to keep the status quo to me.

Comment: I follow the kvm tag across Stack Exchange, and it's only on SU that I have to deal with seeing questions about kvm-switch rather than linux-kvm (which I am probably missing). Oh, and hardwarerecs, but I expect it to mean kvm-switch there. AFAICT everywhere else on the network kvm is the hypervisor.

Comment: [This person](https://superuser.com/q/1400374/144961) made the mistake also.